# using webdriverwait on a particular IWebElement

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am applying the selenium webdriverwait method to a particular IWebElement to fetch some child elements of this IWebElement when they are available. This is my code...

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IList<IWebElement> elementsA = wait.Until<IList<IWebElement>>((d) =>
{
     return driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[@class='boxVerde']"));
});

foreach (IWebElement iwe in elementsA)
{
      wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
      IList<IWebElement> elementsB = wait.Until<IList<IWebElement>>((d) =>
      {
            return iwe.FindElements(By.XPath("tr/td/div/a"));
            //trying to fetch the anchor tags from the element
       });
}
```

it keeps giving me an error saying 'element no longer attached to DOM'...I think that the webdriver wait is simply not working. Am I doing anything wrong guys? much thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Selenium? What browser & version of that browser? Tried using a CSS selector equivalent to that of your XPath query? Do you even *need* the wait?

Comment: Hi Arran, I am using chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0 and the selenium version 2...haven't tried css selectors. Honestly I do not think that I need to wait because I am not changing the dom in anyway before I make the call but since it was givin me the staleElementReferenceException 'element no longer attached to DOM' I assumed I somehow ned the wait...

Comment: What version of Chrome do you have? Selenium version 2 point what? The latest is v2.31, are you using it?

Comment: Chrome v 26.0.1410.43 and selenium v2.31 yes

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are suffering from a Stale Element.

Every WebElement that Selenium finds is actually a reference to a element inside the DOM

Sometimes the JavaScript used on a site will destroy and recreate an element, when this happens your existing reference becomes stale and you will see a StaleElementReferenceException (At least that's what it's called in Java land, You should be seeing something very similar).

So if you ever see a StaleElementReferenceException or a message stating that the "element no longer attached to DOM", it means that the reference to an element in the DOM that you used to have is no longer valid because the element you had a reference to has been destroyed.

This isn't always obvious visually because the original element may have been destroyed and then an identical one recreated, it is however a new element so you need to create a new reference to interact with it.

The way to create a new reference is to find the element again.

It's not totally clear from your questions, but I am assuming you are getting the issue when iterating through the list of anchor elements after finding the table.  If this is the case it suggests that the table has been destroyed and recreated between the point you found the table element and then started to iterate through the anchor elements inside the table.

If this is the case you will need to find the table again, a useful trick is to wait for the table to become stale before you try and find it again.  This way you can be reasonably confident that any JavaScript on the page that is destroying the table and then re-creating it has finished processing.  The [.NET ExpectedConditions class](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/WebDriver.Support/UI/ExpectedConditions.cs) is not as mature as the [Java ExpectedConditions class](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java).  I would suggest having a look at some of the Java ones and porting them across to .NET (It should be fairly trivial, the structure is pretty similar), of particular interest is the Java one that waits for an element to become stale.

Comment: Nice if whoever down voted would explain why considering all of the above is correct...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that some of the tables has been removed for the page. It will be useful to look at events on your page. You should use `//table[@class='boxVerde']/tr/td/div/a` xpath instead of searching inside the element.

Comment: How will using that XPath help if, as you suggest, the table has been removed from the page?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your Webdriver wait to ignore the Exceptions until the polling time overs. The following java method polls the element util 60 seconds and returns if it is loaded else will throws a Timeout Exception. Please convert this to your language as you needed.(Sorry,i am a javaist)

```
public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator, WebDriver driver) {
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
    .withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
    WebElement foo = wait.until(
    new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
    return driver.findElement(locator);
    }
         }  );
    return foo;}
```

In addition to that if you are looking for a single anchor tag element use the xpath as

```
       iwe.FindElements(By.XPath(" //a[text()='anchor tag text']"));
```

or Locate your element via By.linkText("anchor tag text");

```
       iwe.FindElements(By.linkText("anchor tag text"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this. It waits for the Elements to be present within the page.

```
static void ForElementsArePresent(IWebDriver wd, double waitForSeconds, By by)
        {
            try
            {
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wd, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitForSeconds));
                wait.Until(x => (x.FindElements(by).Count > 0));
            }
            catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for element " + by + " to disappear timed out after " + waitForSeconds + " seconds.");
                throw;
            }                       
        }
```